# I have a Galaxy S7 and can launch an app from the widget, but cannot find the application icon to delete the app

Tags: samsung

I have a Galaxy S7 and can launch an app from the widget, but cannot find the application icon to actually uninstall the app.  Any thoughts?

Comment: For what app?  You can go to Settings - Apps (or Application Manager) to find the app, and Uninstall it from there.

Comment: Thats just it, it is not listed there, yet the widgets are still listed and still launch the application

Comment: What application are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your *Settings* app, and find the *Apps* or *Application Manager*. This will show you a list of all the apps installed on your phone.

Another way to do this is to download an app that triggers the app uninstaller for you (e.g. [Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhythm.hexise.uninst&hl=en/) or [Easy Uninstaller App Uninstall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.uninstaller&hl=en)). When you download one of these apps it should list all of the apps on your phone, for you to remove one or more of them at once.

Hope this helps